# Overflowing water flow between two prisms

Tags: fluid-mechanics, open-channel-flow

[image: system schematic]

I have system as seen in the figure. The pump will supply constant volumetric flow rate and the water will fill the first rectangular prism. I couldnt find the water height after water starts to overflow to the upper prism (open channel). The pump will supply 139.57 gph at calculated system head.

Both prisms have b = 28 cm in width and other dimensions given in the figure. (Reynold's Number in the channel flow must be lower than 500 to get a laminar flow.)

How can I determine the water height (y) after the overflow?

Comment: You've made a bunch of statements but didn't ask a question. What is the problem? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: sorry sir, i was trying to ask with "I coulndnt find the water height". I added the question below.

Comment: where is `y` in the diagram? ... the most simiar label that I can see is a `V`

Comment: why do you call it `prism`?

Comment: Just assume incompressible fluid flow, and equilibrium with no water leaving the system (no evaporation, etc), and answer what area you need to match the flow rates.  Once you have an area, you just need to answer what y gives you that area. (Not a complete answer; someone still has some work to do regarding velocities)

Comment: İt is y you can see if you zoom in @jsotola

Comment: @Abel but the problem is velocity depens on area and area depens on velocity tere must be another relation between those. Manning,s equation is used these kind of problems. however ı dont have slope in this system that means water itself will build up slope on the surface. Seems alot complicated.

Comment: Yes and pump head should technically depend on y as well.  Yet they say 139.57 gph, and have s veral distances to the pump from the surface marked.  What does that suggest about your need to assume about y's effect?